# How Synchronization takes place when user update some attributes from Maximo Anywhere app

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

We are trying to analyze how the synchronization takes place in Maximo when user update some attributes from Maximo Anywhere app e.g.

1) When user update WO status in inspection app Or Work Execution app does all the WO object in maximo gets updated or only the delta changes are synchronized?

2) Order of synchronization in case of nested object structures etc..

We analyzed the payload at work light server side but need to understand how the synchronization takes place at Maximo side. Any explanation Or documentation is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Just the delta changes are sent from the Maximo Anywhere layer to the Maximo OSLC layer.  If you're interested, put some breakpoints in the PushingCoordinatorService and watch the payloads that are sent back to the Maximo server in your Chrome simulator.  I recommend the pushTransactionsOfSingleRecord method.

When pulling data from the Maximo OSLC layer, Maximo OSLC does return the entire record, but then Maximo Anywhere locally merges just the differences into it's local copy of the record for WO objects.

If you're interested in how this works, put some breakpoints in the mergeWithExistingRecord method of the PushingCoordinatorService.